# Trying to provide createContext with a default value object which contains functions.Is there any correct way to do so?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-context

Here is my context creator in which i made an initial state for the context but i also have to pass the functions that i want to use by useContext in the project.I passed the functions this way.can anybody tell me a better method to do so. P.S this method works fine but i think itll create problems for big projects

```
import { createContext } from "react"
import { initialState } from "./Initstate"
import { IInitState } from "./alert/IInitState"

export interface IGithubContext {
    State: IInitState,
    searchusers: (login: string) => void,
    clearUsers: () => void,
    getuser: (login: string) => void,
    getuserrepos: (login: string) => void
}

const istate: IGithubContext = {
    State: initialState,
    clearUsers: () => null,
    getuser: () => null,
    getuserrepos: () => null,
    searchusers: () => null
}
const GithubContext = createContext<IGithubContext>(istate)

export default GithubContext
```

Here is my provider which contains functions that i am trying to pass in the value={{}} as you can see

```
import GithubReducer, { Action } from "./GithubReducer"
import GithubContext from "./GithubContext"
import { SET_LOADING, CLEAR_USERS, USER_LOADING, GET_USER, SEARCH_USERS, GET_REPOS } from "./Types"
import { IInitState } from "./alert/IInitState"
import { initialState } from "./Initstate"

const GithubState = (props: any) => {


    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer<React.Reducer<IInitState, Action>>(GithubReducer, initialState)

    const searchusers = async (search: string) => {
        setloading()
        const data = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/search/users?q=${search}`)
        const items = await data.json()
        dispatch({ type: SEARCH_USERS, payload: items.items })
    }

    const getuser = async (login: string) => {
        userloading()
        const data = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${login}`)
        const items = await data.json()
        dispatch({ type: GET_USER, payload: items })
    }

    const getuserrepos = async (login: string) => {
        const data = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${login}/repos?per_page=5&sort=created:asc`)
        const items = await data.json()
        dispatch({ type: GET_REPOS, payload: items })
    }

    const clearUsers = () => dispatch({ type: CLEAR_USERS })
    const setloading = () => dispatch({ type: SET_LOADING })
    const userloading = () => dispatch({ type: USER_LOADING })

    return (
        <GithubContext.Provider value={{
            State: {
                users: state.users,
                user: state.user,
                loading: state.loading,
                userloading: state.userloading,
                repos: state.repos,
                alert: state.alert,
            },
            searchusers,
            clearUsers,
            getuser,
            getuserrepos
        }}>
            {props.children}
        </GithubContext.Provider>
    )

}

export default GithubState
```

Answer (score 0):

The values for the function in the context will default to the value provided when either the `Provider` doesn't enclose the components that need the context or when a component tries to access the values from the context without having access to it(*not children of the `Provider`*).

The current implementation of the default values for the functions for example, `getuser: () => null` just fail silently when some component calls the function `getuser` and has no access to the context provider. So yes this will cause some issues.

***An alternative approach***, throw an error inside the default values for the functions so that when `ComponentA` which is not a child of the `Provider` invokes the function `getuser` or `searchusers`, instead of failing silently the function will throw an error. With this approach at least you will know that some component which doesn't have access to the context tried to access some value from it.

```js
const istate: IGithubContext = {
    State: initialState,
    clearUsers: () => { throw new Error('GithubContext not avaliable') },
    getuser: () => { throw new Error('GithubContext not avaliable') },
    /*other values*/
}
```

Comment: great.I'll try to implement this.Other than that as i have been practicing on context for only over a week with typescript.Is there anything Is it a good practise to provide the initial state which includes functions to context as i have done

Comment: The answer to that question can be very opinionated, and also can vary for application to application. Your implementation is just fine. Just by looking at the snippet that you've provided this is what would I do, separate the functions from the context, and provide them from a different context instead. Of course, I don't know the exact logic of your application so I can not say that will be the best optimal solution. You have to decide and implement what works best for your application.